# How to solve the next integral:$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{\left(y-\frac{z^2+(2-2\rho)zy+(2-2\rho)y^2}{2(1-\rho^2)}\right)} dy$?

Tags: real-analysis

I know that the next equality is true:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{\left(y-\frac{z^2+(2-2\rho)zy+(2-2\rho)y^2}{2(1-\rho^2)}\right)} dy=\sqrt{\pi(1+\rho)}e^{\left(-\frac{(2z-1)+(\rho-z)^2}{4(1-\rho)}\right)}$$

However, I do not get to solve it. I have tried by completing the square but I do not reach this final result.

I think that the nex equality must be hold, but I am notcapable to demonstrate it ( so, I might be mistaken).

$$y-\frac{(z^2+(2-2p)z*y+(2-2p)y^2)}{2(1-p^2)}=\frac{-y^2}{1+p}-(-\frac{(2z‌​-1)+(\rho-z)^2}{4(1-\rho)})$$

So as to can apply that, 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{u^2}{a}} du=\sqrt{a\pi}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
y-\dfrac{z^2+2(1-\rho)zy+2(1-\rho)y^2}{2(1-\rho^2)}=-\dfrac{2(1-\rho)y^2+2(1-\rho)zy-2(1-\rho^2)y+z^2}{2(1-\rho^2)}
$$
this simplifies to
$$
-\dfrac{2(1-\rho)y^2+2(1-\rho)\left(z-(1+\rho)\right)y+z^2}{2(1-\rho^2)}
$$
using completing the square you get
$$
-2(1-\rho)\dfrac{\left(y+\dfrac{z-(1+\rho)}{2}\right)^2+\dfrac{z^2}{2(1-\rho)}-\left(\dfrac{z-(1+\rho)}{2}\right)^2}{2(1-\rho^2)}
$$
or
$$
-\dfrac{\left(y+\dfrac{z-(1+\rho)}{2}\right)^2}{(1+\rho)}-\dfrac{\dfrac{z^2}{2(1-\rho)}-\left(\dfrac{z-(1+\rho)}{2}\right)^2}{1+\rho}
$$
simplifying the the two terms (I will leave this an exercise)
$$
-\dfrac{\left(y+\dfrac{z-(1+\rho)}{2}\right)^2}{(1+\rho)}-\dfrac{1}{4(1-\rho)}\left(z^2+2(1-\rho)z-(1-\rho^2)\right)
$$
lets focus on the last term
$$
z^2+2(1-\rho)z-(1-\rho^2) = z^2-2\rho z + 2z -1+\rho^2 = (z-\rho)^2-\rho^2 +2z -1+\rho^2 = (z-\rho)^2+(2z-1)
$$
so we have
$$
\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\left(y+\frac{z-(1+\rho)}{2}\right)^2}{(1+\rho)}-\frac{(z-\rho)^2+(2z-1)}{4(1-\rho)}}
$$
and your integral is
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\left(y+\frac{z-(1+\rho)}{2}\right)^2}{(1+\rho)}-\frac{(z-\rho)^2+(2z-1)}{4(1-\rho)}}dy = \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{(z-\rho)^2+(2z-1)}{4(1-\rho)}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\left(y+\frac{z-(1+\rho)}{2}\right)^2}{(1+\rho)}}dy 
$$
now remembering make the sub $u = y+\frac{z-(1+\rho)}{2}$ we get
$$
\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{(z-\rho)^2+(2z-1)}{4(1-\rho)}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{u^2}{(1+\rho)}}dy = \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{(z-\rho)^2+(2z-1)}{4(1-\rho)}}\times \sqrt{\pi (1+\rho)}
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot @Chinny84. I finally understood it!